# Encrypting data with ruby decrypting with node

Tags: javascript, ruby, encryption, node.js, cryptography

I want to encrypt some data in a ruby app and then decode it in a nodejs app. I have been trying to get this to work and now I am just trying to encrypt the same piece of data in both languages to get the same result but I can't seem to do it.

```
//js
var crypto = require('crypto');

var key = crypto.createHash('sha1').update('key').digest('hex');
console.log(key); // a62f2225bf70bfaccbc7f1ef2a397836717377de

var encrypted = "";
var cipher = crypto.createCipher('bf-cbc', key);

encrypted += cipher.update('text');
encrypted += cipher.final('hex');

console.log(encrypted); //outputs 4eafd5542875bd3c
```

So it looks like I get a hexadecimal string from the encoding.

```
#ruby
require 'openssl'
require 'digest/sha1'
c = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new("bf-cbc")
c.encrypt
# your pass is what is used to encrypt/decrypt
c.key = key = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest("key")
p key # a62f2225bf70bfaccbc7f1ef2a397836717377de
e = c.update("text")
e << c.final
p e # 皋?;??
```

Is there some sort of encoding issue that I am missing. I tried to base64 decode e but that didn't produce the same result as the node app. Any pointers?

UPDATE: So this is as close as a friend and I can get: https://gist.github.com/a880ea13d3b65a21a99d. Sheesh, I just want to encrypt something in ruby and decrypt it in node.

UPDATE2: Alright, the code in this issue gets me a lot of the way there: https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/1395

Comment: And in ruby apparently 1.8.7 outputs \347\232\213\006\250;\207\302 while 1.9.2 outputs \xE7\x9A\x8B\x06\xA8;\x87\xC2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I want to thank everyone for helping me out. Basically this thread here answers my question: https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/1395. I am going to go ahead and post the two programs in case anyone else has to go through this rigamarole. Keep in mind this isn't mean to be hardcore secure, this is a stepping stone for ruby encrypting data and node decrypting it. You will have to take more steps to make sure higher security measures are taken.

The code is located at this gist: https://gist.github.com/799d6021890f34734470

These were run on ruby 1.9.2p290 and node 0.4.10

Comment: You should call #encrypt or #decrypt on your Cipher as the first operation - see [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/ruby-1.9/classes/OpenSSL/Cipher.html#M006486).

Comment: I think I am doing that with send(mode) on line 10 of encrypt.rb unless I am not understanding what you are saying correclty

Comment: No problem. While my own answer might not be satisfactory for some people (for some reason) it does work as it should so I have to mark it as "the answer"

Answer (score 5):

There are several subtle things that make this fail. The most important one - you are not specifying an IV in your code, so a random value will be generated for you. You would notice that you couldn't even decrypt your ciphertext within the same programming language this way.

So you need to provide an explicit IV to both implementations. But before I show you the code, some advice:

**Key generation**:

Blowfish operates on 64 bit blocks, its key size varies, but OpenSSL (which currently powers both Ruby's and node.js' cipher implementation) uses 128 bit by default, that is 16 bytes.

So your key violates two principles - the first: it's simply too long. It's the hex representation of a SHA-1 hash, which is 20 bytes * 2 = 40 bytes instead of 16. Most of the time this is fine, because the implementation truncates the values appropriately, but that is something you should *not* depend on.

The second mistake, much more severe, is that you use the hex representation instead of the raw bytes: big security issue! Hex characters are not random at all, so in effect you reduce the entropy of your input to half the length (because the underlying bytes were random).

A secure way to generate random keys is using OpenSSL::Random

```
key = OpenSSL::Random.random_bytes(cipher_key_len)
```

A third mistake is to keep your key hard-coded in the sources. It's a bad idea. The least you should do is to store it elsewhere on the file system, where access is tightly restricted. See also [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944018/secure-password-encryption-decryption-of-strings-in-php/6949451#6949451) to another question. The key should be stored out-of-band and only loaded dynamically within the application.

**Cipher**:

Blowfish grows old. It's still considered unbroken in the sense that brute-forcing it is the only way to break it. But a search space of 2^64 is not out of reach for resourceful attackers. So you should indeed move on to AES.

**Padding**:

OpenSSL pads using PKCS5Padding (also known as PKCS7Padding) by default. Ruby profits from this and my bet is node.js utilizes this, too - so you should be safe on this.

Now to the working solution. We need to generate an IV, Blowfish requires it to be 64 bit - 8 bytes. You will need rbytes to get secure random numbers in node. The IV may be hardcoded in your sources (it's public information, no security impact) - but it must be the same on both sides. You should pregenerate a value and use it for both node.js and Ruby.

```
/*node.js*/

var rbytes = require('rbytes');
var iv = rbytes.randomBytes(8);

/*see advice above - this should be out-of-band*/
var key = rbytes.randomBytes(16);
var encrypted = "";
var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('bf-cbc', key, iv);

encrypted += cipher.update('text');
encrypted += cipher.final('hex');
```

Now the Ruby part:

```
require 'openssl'

c = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new("bf-cbc")
c.encrypt
# should be out-of-band again
c.key = OpenSSL::Random.random_bytes(16)
# may be public but has to be the same for Ruby and node
iv = OpenSSL::Random.random_bytes(8)
c.iv = iv 
e = c.update("text")
e << c.final
puts e.unpack('H*')[0]
```

Comment: Generally good advice. I would suggest, however, that the encryption generates an IV and prepends the IV to the ciphertext, so that the output looks like `"#{iv-raw-bytes}#{ciphertext-raw-bytes}"`. Decryption should know the size of the IV and take the first block of the input of that size as the IV with the remainder being ciphertext. That way the IV is random on each encryption, as intended. Note that IV is *not* a secret when each encrypted message has its own IV, so it is safe to share the IV for a single message to the public. The only secret, in this context, is the key.

Comment: That's a good way to do it, Justice. But it's even more complicated, so I tend to start explaining it this way..

Answer (score 0):

Your cyphertext will be some random looking bytes.  Those bytes can be expressed as hex, Base64 or in other ways.  It looks as if your ruby code is outputting the raw bytes.  I suggest that you convert those raw bytes to hex to make your comparison.

Looking at your code, you should also change from Blowfish ("bf") to AES.  Blowfish has a 64-bit block size and is now obsolete.

You would do well to explicitly specify padding, PKCS7 is common

Comment: It is e.unpack('H*') but of course the values from the node encryption and the ruby encryption don't equal

Comment: If the still don't match then check what padding each version is using.  Better to specify it explicitly, as I said.