# AES-256-CBC with Digest from Ruby to NodeJS

Tags: ruby, node.js

I am hoping someone can shed some light on a problem that has been vexing me for the last few hours.

I am trying to decode a string that has been encoded in Ruby thus:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'base64'
require 'openssl'
require 'openssl/cipher'
require 'openssl/digest'

aes = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new('aes-256-cbc')
aes.encrypt
aes.key = Digest::SHA256.digest('IHazSekretKey') 

p Base64.encode64( aes.update('text to be encrypted') << aes.final )
```

Executing the above spits out: "3P86KyOrN2QJ/HFxxo3b7kAsxTgpDMMjROUPclsuXj0=\n"

I now try to decrypt this string in NodeJS 0.6.17

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var crypto = require('crypto'); 

function decrypto(toDecryptStr) {
  var result,
    encoded   = new Buffer(toDecryptStr, 'base64'),
    decodeKey = crypto.createHash('sha256').update('IHazSekretKey', 'ascii').digest(),
    decipher  = crypto.createDecipher('aes-256-cbc', decodeKey);

  result = decipher.update(encoded);
  result += decipher.final();

  return result;
};

console.log(decrypto('3P86KyOrN2QJ/HFxxo3b7kAsxTgpDMMjROUPclsuXj0='));
console.log(decrypto('3P86KyOrN2QJ/HFxxo3b7kAsxTgpDMMjROUPclsuXj0=\n')
```

The second script yields:

```
nazar@xfce:~/tmp/tst$ ./js_decrypt 
Å'{ H£V)ÜB
Å'{ H£V)ÜB
```

Any help would be very much appreciated as my only remaining option now is to drown myself in a barrel of [Jamerson || Kirin Ichiban] (I'm only kidding)

PS there is a similar question on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7192401/encrypting-data-with-ruby-decrypting-with-node), which sadly hasn't yielded any inspiration for my case.

Comment: Between node.js bugs regarding using base64 and incomplete documentation that refers to things that don't exist in stable, I give up. Pass the bottle please. Btw your origKey also seems to be different in the ruby and node, but that could be because I'm converting to base64 to check and that apparently has a bug. :-S

Comment: Passing you the bottle shortly @Gerry.... I'm going to have another crack at this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The critical missing piece is the IV, which is required when encryption/decryption is to be made across language boundaries as apparently the encrypter will generate a random IV (or something like that - still don't understand how Ruby decrypts the string without an IV.... but then what do I know....), if one is not provided.

The following snippets show how to encrypt a string in Ruby and decrypt in NodeJS.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'openssl'
require 'base64'
require 'openssl/cipher'
require 'openssl/digest'

aes = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new('aes-256-cbc')
aes.encrypt
aes.key = Digest::SHA256.digest('IHazSekretKey') 
aes.iv  = '1234567890123456'

p Base64.encode64( aes.update('text to be encrypted') << aes.final )
```

The above prints: "eiLbdhFSFrDqvUJmjbUgwD8REjBRoRWWwHHImmMLNZA=\n"

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var crypto = require('crypto'); 

function decrypto(toDecryptStr) {
  var result,
    encoded   = new Buffer(toDecryptStr, 'base64'),
    decodeKey = crypto.createHash('sha256').update('IHazSekretKey', 'ascii').digest(),
    decipher  = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-cbc', decodeKey, '1234567890123456');

  result = decipher.update(encoded);
  result += decipher.final();

  return result;
}

console.log(decrypto('eiLbdhFSFrDqvUJmjbUgwD8REjBRoRWWwHHImmMLNZA=\n'))
```

The JS script now properly decrypts the string.

One unfortunate side effect is that existing encrypted data will need to be decrypted and then re-encrypted with an IV that is then used in the decrypting implementation.

A PITA but nonetheless a working solution.

Comment: "still don't understand how Ruby decrypts the string without an IV" >
The IV defaults to null: http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/Cipher.html#method-i-decrypt Well done btw.

Comment: Ahh.. that explains it :). Thanks @Gerry.

Comment: You're very welcome. I actually though it might be an IV problem at first, however I couldn't seem to get it working in my testing, so I had figured it was something else. :)

Comment: hey nazar are you sure about your script is running successfully. I am just came around this situation where data encrypt in ruby and i want to decrypt in node so i follow your code but it's stuck up at decrypt.

Comment: @Harshal_m_joshi, yes it works and we've been using it in production for quite a while now. It is critical that IV be identical across language boundaries. HTH and good luck.

Comment: @nazar yep it's works with aes-256-cbc schemes. I was trying with aes-128-cbc with this it get's failed. just try to encrypt and decrypt with aes-128-cbc. sorry, forgot to mentioned this(aes-128-cbc) in previous comment.

Comment: Is there a way to get it without IV?